# Can you add an aggregate pipeline to document .save() action?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I use mongoose with mongodb and while updating a document, I first find the document, modify the resultant document object and then do a `.save()` on the document.

Now I want to add an aggregate pipeline to the save operation so as to control the document response better and so I was wondering if this possible.

I read that the update query can have the pipeline attached to it but does that also apply to the save action?

Answer (score 0):

as far as I am concern in the current version of MongoDB(4.4), the only methods that allow aggregate pipelines are those concerning updateAndModify, and Update. Thus, the limit use that mongoose might bring to this subject. What I would recommend in your case is that you use the aggregation pipeline with `Model.findOneAndUpdate()`. Here is an example that you might follow: [example of aggregate using Model.findOneAndUpdate()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/#findoneandupdate-agg-pipeline)
Also you might notice that this is the documentation for MongoDB and not Mongoose. I tend to find it difficult to find useful information for more specific use cases like this one in the docs of Mongoose, therefore the link in MongoDB. It will work the same as with a model from Mongoose so take a shot!

Comment: Thank you for the response. I guess I knew I couldn't do it with the save since I couldn't find anything about it. Will look into the example you mentioned.

Comment: you´re welcome. Depending on your use case scenario you might also want to check map-reduce. have fun! https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/map-reduce/